# Change Node Shape

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I need to change the "Shape" and color properties of a node in Vis.js.
My code is very simple:

```
const stepNode = this.findStepById(node);
stepNode.options.shape = 'hexagon';
stepNode.options.color.background = '#39e600';
this.visNetwork.redraw();
```

My problem is that the color of the node is changed with no problem, but the Shape remains without modifications, Anybody knows how I can change the shape of a node on the fly?